# How to display curl's individual Exit Status from multiple requests?

Tags: bash, curl, url

My question is simple - is there a way to display curl's individual [Exit Status](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-returns) for each URL when curl is doing multiple requests?

Let's imagine that I need to check sites `a.com`, `b.com`, `c.com` and see their:

- HTTP return code
- if HTTP return code is `000`, I need to display curl's `exit code`.

NOTE - `a.com`, `b.com`, `c.com` are used as an example in this code/question. In the real script, I do have a list of valid URLs - more than 400 of them with non-overlapping patterns - and they return a variety of HTTP codes - 200/4xx/5xx as well as 000.

The 000 is the case when curl could not make a connection but provides Exit Codes to understand what prevented it to establish a connection. In my cases, there are a number of exit codes as well - 6, 7, 35, 60.

I tried to run the following code

```
unset a
unset rep
a=($(curl -s --location -o /dev/null -w "%{response_code}\n" {https://a.com,https://b.com,https://a.com}))
rep+=("$?")
printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"
echo
printf '%s\n' "${rep[@]}"
```

While the above code returns the HTTP return code for each individual request, the Exit Code is displayed only from the last request.

```
000
000
000

60
```

I do need the ability to log individual Exit Code when I supply multiple URLs to curl.
Is there a workaround/solution for this problem?

Some additional information: currently I put all my URLs in an array and run a cycle thru it checking each URL separately. However, going thru 400 URLs takes 1-2 hours and I need to somehow speed up the process.
I did try to use -Z with curl. While it did speed up the process about 40-50%, it didn't help because in addition to show only the above-mentioned last Exit Status, the Exit Status, in this case, is always displayed as 0, which is not correct.

P.S. I am open to using any other command-line tool if it can resolve the above problem - parallel checking of 10s/100s of URLs with logging of their HTTP codes and if the connection can't be established - log additional information like curl's Exit Codes do.

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is the point of braces in `{https://a.com,https://b.com,https://a.com}`? I think Bash expands this string to `https://a.com https://b.com https://a.com` which is even a little simpler; so why not to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) by using the latter form directly? If you used `https://{a,b,a}.com`, then I would understand because this form is shorter and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). For now I think the braces only obfuscate the code. What am I missing?

Comment: Fair question. Let me explain.
As it is documented at [curl's howto](https://ec.haxx.se/cmdline/cmdline-globbing), the expansion's purpose is to apply supplied curl parameters for every site in the braces. Without braces, the alternative is to use switch --next and then repeat all curl's parameters for each site.
You are correct that ``https://{a,b,a}.com`` would be better stylistically for this particular example, however, as I mentioned in the description, a/b/c is used for illustrative purposes. In my real code with 400 URLs they are different and have no common patterns.

Comment: OK, so it's deeper. The braces in the howto are quoted. Your question is tagged `bash`. Bash expands unquoted braces. In your code `curl` doesn't see the braces, it sees what the shell gives to it. Now I'm not saying it doesn't work for you in this particular case. I'm saying it's Bash who handles the syntax when you think it's `curl`. This misunderstanding may lead to subtle bugs.

Comment: I understand my concern is irrelevant to the issue apparently; illustrative purposes, I get it. Still if you ever want to use braces with `curl` in serious purposes, keep in mind the shell may handle them first in some circumstances; this may affect the overall result.

Comment: Understood. When enclosing expressions inside braces in double-quotes in my case output/result is the same.
URL statements in curl examples on that site are always enclosed in double-quotes, however, it does not really affect the outcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Analysis

The exit code is named "*exit* code" because it is returned when a command exits. If you run just one `curl` then it will exit exactly once.

`curl`, when given one or more URLs, might provide a way to retrieve a code equivalent to the exit code of separate `curl` handling just the current URL; it would be something similar to `%{response_code}` you used. Unfortunately it seems there is no such functionality (yet; [add it maybe](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/help-us.html)). To get N exit codes you need N `curl` processes. You need to run something like this N times:

```
curl … ; echo "$?"
```

I understand your N is about 400, you tried this in a loop and it took hours. Well, spawning 400 `curl`s (even with 400 `echo`s, if `echo` wasn't a builtin; and even with 400 (sub)shells, if needed) is not that time consuming. The culprit is in the fact you run all these *synchronously* (didn't you?).

---

#### Simple loop and its problems

It's possible to loop and run the snippet asynchronously:

```
for url in … ; do
   ( curl … ; echo "$?" ) &
done
```

There are several problems with this simple approach though:

1. You cannot easily limit the number of `curl`s that run simultaneously, there is no queue. This can be very bad in terms of performance and available resources.
2. Concurrent output from two or more commands (e.g from two or more `curl`s) may get [interleaved](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476089/108618), possibly mid-line.
3. Even if output from each command separately looks fine, `curl` or `echo` from another subshell may cut in between `curl` and its corresponding `echo`.
4. There is no guarantee a subshell invoked earlier starts (or ends) printing before a subshell invoked later.

---

#### `parallel`

The right tool is `parallel`. Basic variant of the tool (from `moreutils`, at least [in Debian](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/moreutils/parallel.1.en.html)) solves (1). It probably solves (2) in some circumstances. This is irrelevant anyway because this variant does not solve (3) or (4).

[GNU `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) solves all these problems.

- It solves (1) by design.
- It solves (2) and (3) with its `--group` option:

  > `--group`
  > Group output. Output from each job is grouped together and is only printed when the command is finished. Stdout (standard output) first followed by stderr (standard error). […]

  <sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#OPTIONS))</sup>

  which is the default, so usually you don't have to use it explicitly.
- It solves (4) with its `--keep-order` option:

  > `--keep-order`
  > `-k`
  > Keep sequence of output same as the order of input. Normally the output of a job will be printed as soon as the job completes. […] `-k` only affects the order in which the output is printed - not the order in which jobs are run.

  <sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#OPTIONS))</sup>

In Debian GNU `parallel` is in a package named `parallel`. The rest of this answer uses GNU `parallel`.

---

#### Basic solution

```
<urls parallel -j 40 -k 'curl -s --location -o /dev/null -w "%{response_code}\n" {}; echo "$?"'
```

where `urls` is a file with URLs and `-j 40` means we allow up to 40 parallel jobs (adjust it to your needs and abilities). In this case it's safe to embed `{}` in the shell code. It's an exception explicitly mentioned in this answer: [*Never embed `{}` in the shell code!*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618)

The output will be like

```
404
0
200
0
000
7
…
```

Note the single-quoted string is the shell code. Within it you can implement some logic, so exit code `0` is never printed. If I were you I would print it anyway, in the same line, on the *leading* position:

```
<urls parallel -j 40 -k '
   out="$(
      curl -s --location -o /dev/null -w "%{response_code}" {}
   )"
   printf "%s %s\n" "$?" "$out"'
```

Now even if some `curl` is manually killed before it prints, you will get something in the first column. This is useful for parsing (we'll return to it). Example:

```
0 404
0 200
7 000
…
143 
…
```

where `143` means `curl` was terminated (see [*Default exit code when process is terminated*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99112/108618)).

---

#### With arrays

If your URLs are in an array named `urls`, avoid this syntax:

```
parallel … ::: "${urls[@]}"    # don't
```

`parallel` is an external command. If the array is large enough then you will hit [`argument list too long`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647755/10765659). Use this instead:

```
printf '%s\n' "${urls[@]}" | parallel …
```

It will work because in Bash `printf` is a builtin and therefore everything before `|` is handled internally by Bash.

To get from `urls` array to `a` and `rep` arrays, proceed like this:

```
unset a
unset rep
while read -r repx ax; do
   rep+=("$repx")
   a+=("$ax")
done < <(printf '%s\n' "${urls[@]}" \
         | parallel -j 40 -k '
              out="$(
                 curl -s --location -o /dev/null -w "%{response_code}" {}
              )"
         printf "%s %s\n" "$?" "$out"')
printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"
echo
printf '%s\n' "${rep[@]}"
```

---

#### Notes

- If we generated exit codes in the second column (which is easier, you don't need a helper variable like `out`) and adjusted our `read` accordingly, so it's `read -r ax repx`, then a line `<empty ax><space>143` would save `143` into `ax` because `read` ignores leading spaces ([it's complicated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/108618)). By reversing the order we avoid a bug in our code. A line like `143<space><empty ax>` is properly handled by `read -r repx ax`.
- You will hopefully be able to check 400 URLs in few minutes. The duration depends on how many jobs you allow in parallel (`parallel -j …`), but also on:

  - how fast the servers respond;
  - how much data and how fast `curl`s download;
  - options like `--connect-timeout` and `--max-time` (consider using them).

Comment: Interesting fact: the author and maintainer of GNU `parallel` is Ole Tange, our fellow user [here on Super User](https://superuser.com/users/41337) (although more active on Unix & Linux SE). I think it's great developers provide support here (on Stack Exchange in general). Check if you can find the main author of `curl`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did read about the parallel a couple of years ago but didn't think about using it.

Comment: I did implement your solution - processing time of 400 URLs with ``parallel -j 20`` went down from 40 min to 5. Thanks again. 
My question is - is there a way in your example to get an individual string passed to the parallel in the form of variable?

Comment: @Invisible999 A common, fixed string? The environment variable is a generic way to make some string available to any command (the command may or may not be designed to use it  though). Furthermore "passed to the `parallel`" and "passed to the code run by `parallel`" are not equivalent. See `man 1 parallel`, option named `--env`. If this is not what you want then you need to bee more descriptive. Probably not in a comment. Ask a new question maybe.

Comment: @Invisible999 Oh, now I see [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1607521/432690). Sorry, I interpreted "get an individual string passed …" similarly to "get something done". It seems you want to "get a string that was passed". English is a foreign language to me.