# GNU Parallel usage - how get currently passed string to parallel?

Tags: bash, curl, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I am using GNU parallel and want to understand - how can I get the individual string passed to each parallel command?

As an example, [GNU Parallel documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/GNU-Parallel.html) shows how to move files from the current directory to another:

```
ls | parallel mv {} destdir
```

So is there a way to get/print each file individually which was passed to parallel?

**Case for parallel processing**

I need to do parallel processing of checking multiple sites and record

- http return code (2xx, 4xx, 5xx)
- The source URL
- The ultimate destination URL
- the curl exit code

Here is the code which does this:

```
    unset return_code_array
    unset destination_url_array
    unset exit_code_array

    while read -r return_code_var destination_url_var exit_code_var; do

        destination_url_array+=("$destination_url_var")
        exit_code_array+=("$exit_code_var")
        return_code_array+=("$return_code_var")

    done < <(printf '%s\n' "${all_valid_URLs_array[@]}" | parallel -j 20 -k 'curl --max-time 20 -sL -o /dev/null -w "%{response_code} %{url_effective} " {}; printf "%s %s\n" "$?" ')
```

As a result, I have three arrays and they hold the HTTP return code, ultimate destination URL, and the curl exit code status for each corresponding line for the `all_valid_URLs_array` entries. I at the same time need to do some processing for each `destination_url_var` - like comparing if it matches to the source URL, but have no idea how to get the string which was passed to parallels.

Currently, I am running a second loop after the above one for such processing but want to know if I want to accomplish is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: If you checked closely, the example was taken directly from parallel's documentation for illustrative purposes. I am not using ls, you can direct your valid concerns to those who wrote parallel's documentation. Thanks.

Comment: @Cyrus Parsing `ls` (without any options) is in practice safe if you know your filenames do not contain newlines. In my 25 years of sysadmin I have only seen that from malicious users, f*cked filesystems, or test files I have created myself.

Comment: @OleTange: I agree that in this case it is fine as long as the filename does not contain newlines. For safety reasons I recommend switching to GNU find's and parallel's `-0`.

Comment: @Cyrus The alternative is not `find` because you need to disable recursion and remove `./` from the . The alternative is `printf "%s\0" *` (but it does not work in *csh if the list is too long).

Comment: @OleTange: I would have used `find -maxdepth 1 -printf "%f\0"` but your suggestion is probably easier to remember and with `bash` it's a builtin.

Comment: @Cyrus You will still get . in your output. So you need to remove that, too.

Comment: @OleTange: This is an important issue. In this case, a solution with `find` would be even longer: `find . -maxdepth 1 ! -path . -printf "%f\0"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `'curl … {}; printf "%s %s\n" "$?" '` (why the second `%s`?) is a single-quoted piece of shell code. In it you can use `{}` more than once:

```
curl … {}; printf "%s %s\n" "$?" {}
```

Alternatively create a variable and use it as many times as you want. The name of the variable can be descriptive, this is an advantage. There's another advantage: in general what gets substituted for `{}` can be a long string, substituting it many times may bloat the code `parallel` will pass to particular shells. IMO it's better to substitute once and let the shell save the string and reuse it:

```
source_URL={}; curl … "$source_URL"; printf "%s %s\n" "$?" "$source_URL"
```

<sup>In case of GNU `parallel` it's safe to embed `{}` in the shell code. It's an exception explicitly mentioned in this answer: [*Never embed `{}` in the shell code!*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618). You probably already know this, the remark is for a general audience.</sup>

Note you need to adjust your `read` in the main loop, it now has to read into *four* variables. This way you will transfer the source URL from the inside of `parallel` to the main loop where you can compare it to `destination_url_var` or do whatever you want.

Still in this approach "whatever you want" is not parallelized.

If you capture the output from `curl` to separate variables inside the shell code run by `parallel` (instead of just printing it to be captured outside of `parallel`) then you will be able to do comparison (or whatever you want) *there*, in parallel. And e.g. `printf` *conditionally*. It's up to you where you implement the desired logic, as long as the inside of `parallel` generates output in the form expected by the outside `read`.

The shell code passed to `parallel` still needs to be single-quoted. As it grows, you may need to use (embed) single-quotes in this very code; then quoting will get somewhat complicated and less readable. In such situation consider moving the code to a separate script where you can quote independently. You will invoke it from the main script like this:

```
while read … ; done < <( … | parallel -j 20 -k 'path/to/separate_script {}' )
```

Inside the `separate_script` the string substituted for `{}` will be available as `$1` (don't forget to [double-quote it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618)).

Comment: Instead of moving the complex quoted code into a separate script I often just define a function and call that (remember to `export -f the_function` first). This way you can keep the code in the same script.