# ssh commands in cron jobs on remote server

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, cron, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

It is known that cron and ssh-agent do not communicate and hence ssh commands cannot be trivially run under cron. There are solutions involving keychain etc that make it possible to do this. However in my case I need to run a cron job on a remote server (where I am logged in via ssh with agent forwarding) that will execute on a second remote server using ssh. So my keys are not present in the first remote server where the ssh command originates. All solutions for running ssh under cron assume the presence of ssh keys on the server of origin. How to run ssh commands with cron when there are no ssh keys present? I am thinking one needs to make cron aware of ssh-agent variables. But I am not sure how to do this. Any idea how to do this?

This is my crontab on remote server 1:

```
*/1 * * * * ssh root@remote2 "some command" >> /home/output.log
```

edit1: remote2 is just an example. This has to be repeated for ~100 servers.

### edit2: SSH_AUTH_SOCK solution attempt

Contents of ~/.ssh folder:

```
$ ls -lt /home/centos/.ssh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 centos centos    31 24. Mär 15:13 ssh_auth_sock -> /tmp/ssh-59Ay2ronRN/agent.24129
```

Contents of crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/centos/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock;/bin/bash /home/test.sh
```

Contents of /home/test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "`date +%FT%T` $0: test cronjob from centos .. $SSH_AUTH_SOCK" >> ${runlog}
/usr/bin/ssh remote2 "sudo less /var/log/program.log | grep 'NOT ENDING'" >>${runlog} 2>&1
```

Contents of ${runlog}:

```
2022-03-24T15:22:01 /home/test.sh: test cronjob from centos .. 
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

### edit3: SSH_AUTH_SOCK solution update (SOLVED)

Declaring SSH_AUTH_SOCK as follows worked:

```
…
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/…
*/1 * * * * ssh …
…
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't setup the cron directly on that second server?

Comment: You could just install an ssh key on the host where the ssh command runs. There are ways to limit the key to just running particular commands.

Comment: @LPChip I need to collect data from ~100 servers and collect it in one server. Hence ssh is inevitable.

Kenster: I don't want to put private keys on server 1. Also I would have to copy the keys to ~100 servers. Regardless I think it is important to solve this problem of making cron talk to the running ssh-agent without involving keys.

Comment: Sorry if my response felt like an attack. You did not mention anything about this being for ~100 servers in your question. This does change the scope of the question and therefor should be in the question I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

> I am thinking one needs to make cron aware of ssh-agent variables.

`SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is the relevant variable.

The variable seen by `ssh` spawned by cron on the remote server 1 doesn't have to hold the same value as the variable seen by you after `ssh`-ing to the remote server 1. It should eventually lead to the same socket. Proceed like this:

1. After logging in to the remote server 1 (with agent forwarding), create a symbolic link with a fixed name in some private location. The link should point to the currently used socket. As this is closely related to SSH, your `~/.ssh` is a good location; I assume it's private (permissions `700`).

   ```
   ln -s "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
   ```
2. In your crontab on the remote server 1 (`crontab -e`) place the following line *before* the `ssh` line(s):

   ```
   SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/your/homedir/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
   ```

   Note cron expands neither `~/` nor `$HOME`, therefore you need to specify `/your/homedir/` explicitly. Use the actual path of your home directory on the remote server 1. Your crontab will look like this:

   ```
   …
   SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/…
   */1 * * * * ssh …
   …
   ```
3. Before logging out of the remote server 1 (i.e. before terminating the forwarding of the agent), remove the link:

   ```
   rm ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
   ```

When you log in again, repeat step 1; before logging out, repeat step 3; these steps can be automated. The variable in your crontab is static, there is no need to repeat step 2.

Note automating these steps reliably is not a trivial task in general. In general you can connect to the remote server 1 multiple times and disconnect in any order. Handling the symbolic link manually is quite simple though: the code is static (the variable part is behind the variable), you only need to think if, when and in what session to use it.

---

#### Doubts

- If there is no `~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock` or the link is broken, or the forwarding of the agent is no more, then the `ssh` command in the crontab will fail. And you're going to specify ~100 commands. Does cron send you an e-mail after a command prints to its stderr? You redirected stdout but not stderr.
- The commands [will be run asynchronously](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283981/108618). The results from `some command`s may get interleaved in the `output.log`. Unless you use separate logs; but then (and not only then)…
- What if `some command` takes more than 1 minute?

Consider a script that checks if the agent responds (checking the exit status of `ssh-add -l >/dev/null 2>&1` should be enough). Consider GNU `parallel` (compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1594555/432690)). Ask yourself if cron really fits the task.

---

#### Vulnerability?

Neglecting `rm ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock` or being disconnected from the remote server 1 before you `rm` will leave our symbolic link as broken (socket removed, the link still there). Imagine an attacker (another legitimate user of server 1) who manages to predict or guess the path your dangling link still points to. Imagine they create their socket at this exact path and grant permissions to your user.

In my tests with OpenSSH in Kubuntu paths are like `/tmp/ssh-GjYJe19sjiAb/agent.372911`. An attacker can `ls /tmp` and observe there is `ssh-GjYJe19sjiAb/` and I'm the owner. They cannot know the next component (`agent.372911`). Still they can notice when the directory disappears, they can re-create it as theirs. Next they plant their socket leading to their agent and create million symlinks with different possible names. And they make sure my user can access the directory and the socket.

Eventually the `ssh` from crontab follows our symlink and the attacker's, it uses the attacker's agent. How bad can it be?

- If some `ssh` from crontab (possibly `ssh` unrelated to the task in question) uses a key file stored on the remote server 1, logs in successfully to somewhere and its config states `AddKeysToAgent=yes`, then the key will be added to the attacker's agent and they will be able to authenticate with it.
- The attacker can add their keys to the agent. Your `ssh`(s) from crontab will happily try to use them. Seems harmless. Not if `root@remote2` effectively recognizes users by their keys (e.g. AFAIK `git@github.com` does this) and the attacker is also a legitimate user whose key is recognized on `remote2`. By making your `ssh` use their key, the attacker executes `some command` in their environment on `remote2`, they can easily print anything to your `output.log`. Maybe in this particular case it's just a log; however in general you may want to make some important decisions based on what you get.

Hopefully neither scenario applies in your case. If so, a dangling symlink is not a problem. Instead of `rm` before you log out from the remote server 1, you can `rm` just after you log in, just before you `ln`.

Comment: thanks. I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: I edited the question with the result of your suggestion. Could you see what went wrong?

Comment: @DuraiArasan "In your crontab on the remote server 1 place the following line before the `ssh` line(s)" exactly means "place this one line before the `ssh` lines you already have or are going to add", not "merge this line with something". The line I gave you is a *standalone full line*; `ssh` lines should come as separate lines that follow.

Comment: thanks! it works. It remains to be seen if I can used it in chained scripts. Nevertheless this is the best answer. More tomorrow.